# Missing jar source attachments, thread exceptions, null pointer exceptions, when trying to read from SQLite database on Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jar, nullpointerexception

I'm writing an Android project in Eclipse and running it on a 3.1 tablet.

When I try to fetch a line from my SQLite database with

```
int Get(long rowId){
    System.out.println("Works up to here!!!"); //things are fine
    Cursor c = myDbHelper.fetch(rowId); //things are not fine
    ...
}
```

I get the following in logcat:

```
Works up to here!!!
threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40142760)
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at blah blah blah...
```

And when I debug, that same spot gives me

```
The JAR file ...\android.jar has no source attachment.
```

I find neither of these messages helpful. My code works right up until the above line, but doesn't go into fetch() in my DataBaseHelper class. I know that the class (including open(), create(), fetch(), and all that) works because it's from http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ and I wrote another program with the same database file using the same DataBaseHelper class. 
Short of posting my 900 lines of code for someone to go through and help me out, what should I look for that might be causing this problem?

Comment: the stacktrace for the NullPointerException should tell you *the exact line* it is occurring. Knowing this is immensely helpful for debugging. Is myDbHelper null?

Comment: @matt Yes, it is the c = myDbHelper.fetch(rowId) line. myDbHelper has no reason to be null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it was a stupid little mistake. I had two "myDbHelper"s. Fixed that and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you instantiating `myDbHelper`?

The linked-to source code has

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
```

are you sure you didn't leave this out?

Also, when debugging, the stacktrace is of immense value - the `blah blah` part you cut out likely points to the **exact** line where the NPE occurs, which should give you a huge hint as to which reference is null. Sharing this information - what exact line of code of yours it occurs at - makes it much easier for us to help you.